# Avoid no-sequences inside map function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a array which I want to loop through so I use the map prototype.
Inside the callbackfn of each element I want to run several expressions.

```
const test = [{ name: "foo", value: "1" }, { name: "bar", value: "2" }, { name: "x", value: "3" }]
  let found = false;
  test.map(name => (
    console.log(name.name),
    console.log(name.value),
    found = true
  ));
```

I've separated each expression with a `,`. Whilst this runs correctly and produces the correct results I can see my eslint saying **Unexpected use of comma operator                 no-sequences**

How am I meant to put multiple expressions inside the map function?

Comment: should be `;` not `,`

Comment: `map` transforms an array of one kind into another array. Are you looking for `filter` perhaps as a truth test?

Comment: @AZ_ the OP seems to be using parens which would make using semicolons a syntax error.

Comment: Hi @AZ_ If I replace `,` with `;` I get `Unexpected token, expected "," `.

Comment: @DanielJ use a code-block `{}` for your function body and then use `;` to end each statement. If all you want to do is loop, you can use `forEach` instead of `map`, as `map` returns a _new_ array (see docs on how to use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) correctly)

Comment: @DanielJ use curly braces instead of parens for the map function body.

Comment: @evolutionxbox didn't see that, should be `{
    console.log(name.name);
    console.log(name.value);
    found = true
  })`

Comment: @mrblewog All I want to do is loop through each item of a array then perform some multiple actions on the object. I just added some bare minimum code so as to make it apparent.

Comment: @DanielJ `forEach` then https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Thanks @mrblewog, yes that's the prototype I wanted. I was using `map` as originally I was creating an returns array but now I am not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How am I meant to put multiple expressions inside the map function?

Use curly braces:

```
test.map(name => {
   console.log(name.name)
   console.log(name.value)
   found = true
});
```

Though `map` doesn't look the right choice for this as pointed out others - looks like you should use `filter`, but the same rules apply for multiple statements.

Normal brackets are a shorthand for 'implied return', where you can omit the `{}` and the `return` keyword if your function only contains one expression. In fact, you can usually omit the brackets too!

So these are equivalent:

```
test.filter(name => {
    let found = false
    if(name==='sarah'){
       found = true
    }
    return found 
}

test.filter(name => name === 'sarah')
```

Comment: Thanks @Will Jenkins, Worked perfectly.

Comment: Looks like his intent is not to filter an array, but check if a value is present. Filter will work, but iterate within entire array even if the first item matches. Array.some() is the correct.

Comment: ah ok, the intent is kind of beside the point of the OP though eh

Comment: Hi @WillJenkins I'm running into this again. In react I need to use .map to return multiple components.
https://jsfiddle.net/v4gLkxjy/
But in this case, if I get told `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`

If instead of curly braces I have brackets and instead of a semicolon I have a comma, my code works as intended

Comment: if you need to return a component (and you're using `{}` with multiple expressions), you need to `return` something at the end!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness from my comment then: use `forEach` and things other people have mentioned.

```
const test = [{ name: "foo", value: "1" }, { name: "bar", value: "2" }, { name: "x", value: "3" }]
  let found = false;
  test.forEach(name => {
    console.log(name.name);
    console.log(name.value);
    found = true;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code, since the correct syntax for an arrow function with multiple lines of code is:

```
(params) => {
  // Your code here with semicolon at line end
}
```

Note the use of curly braces instead of parentheses and the semicolon instead of comma at line end.

Also, since you are seeking for some value inside and don't care about it position, you can use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead. It will be more efficient since it stops on first result:

```
let found = test.some((name) => {
  if (your condition here) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```