# Array reduce Unexpected use of comma operator no-sequences

Tags: javascript

I am getting an "Unexpected use of comma operator no-sequences" warning -- on the .reduce - but I am not sure how to resolve this.

```
const getQueryParams = () => 
  this.props.location.search
    .replace('?', '')
    .split('&')
    .reduce((r,e) => (r[e.split('=')[0]] = decodeURIComponent(e.split('=')[1]), r), {});
```

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+no-sequences+in+arrow+function) of [Avoid no-sequences inside map function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60615901/4642212).

Comment: similar issue - but its not inside a map function though

Comment: Why do you think this matters at all? Do you get a completely different ESLint warning if you replace `reduce` by `map`? The warning is about the content of the function, not about the _name_ of the function.

Comment: It matters - because its not a map - it was a reduce - so that topic didn't match when making the question. So its not a duplicate of the exact same scenario, even if its about the content.

Comment: By the way, it looks like you’re trying to parse URL parameters. Simply use `this.props.location.searchParams` instead, or `new URL(this.props.location).searchParams`, depending on if `this.props.location` is a `URL`. You can call `.entries()` on it and wrap it in `Object.fromEntries(`…`)` to get a plain object. See [`URL.prototype.searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams).

Answer (score 6):

The code quoted uses (some would say *ab*uses) the comma operator in order to avoid using the function body form of an arrow function. The minimal change to remove the comma operator is to put `{}` around the function body and do an explicit `return`:

```
const getQueryParams = () => 
    this.props.location.search
        .replace('?', '')
        .split('&')
        .reduce((r,e) => {
            r[e.split('=')[0]] = decodeURIComponent(e.split('=')[1]);
            return r;
        }, {});
```

---

As a matter of style, though, I'd suggest not using `reduce` there at all. (I have a [fair](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1213077702300852224) bit of [company](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544) disliking `reduce` outside of Functional Programming with predefined, reusable reducers.)

In that code, the `reduce` is just a loop; the accumulator never changes, it's always the same object. So I'd just use a loop:

```
const getQueryParams = () => {
    const result = {};
    for (const e of this.props.location.search.replace("?", "").split("&")) {
        result[e.split("=")[0]] = decodeURIComponent(e.split("=")[1]);
    }
    return result;
};
```

I'd probably also remove the redundant call to `split`:

```
const getQueryParams = () => {
    const result = {};
    for (const e of this.props.location.search.replace("?", "").split("&")) {
        const [key, value] = e.split("=");
        result[key] = decodeURIComponent(value);
    }
    return result;
};
```

Finally, both keys *and* values in query strings are URI-encoded, so `decodeURIComponent` should be used on both:

```
const getQueryParams = () => {
    const result = {};
    for (const e of this.props.location.search.replace("?", "").split("&")) {
        const [key, value] = e.split("=");
        result[decodeURIComponent(key)] = decodeURIComponent(value);
    }
    return result;
};
```

It'll work without if the keys are just alphanumerics and such, but it's not *correct*.

---

Stepping back from the syntax, though, you don't need to invent your own function for parsing query string parameters. Browsers [already have one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams):

```
const getQueryParams = () => Object.fromEntries(
    new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search)
    .entries()
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const search = "?bar=Testing%201%202%203&baz=2";
console.log(
    Object.fromEntries(
        new URLSearchParams(search)
        .entries()
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite the `reduce` call, so to avoid an assignment expression (and comma operator), turning the arrow function expression syntax into block syntax (see [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#basic_syntax)):

```
.reduce((r,e) => {
     r[e.split('=')[0]] = decodeURIComponent(e.split('=')[1]);
     return r;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use `Object.assign`:

```js
let search = ["item=test","name=code%28","foo=%20bar"]

let result = search.reduce((r,e) => 
Object.assign(r,{[e.split('=')[0]] : decodeURIComponent(e.split('=')[1])}), {});

console.log(result)
```